# Ubuntu 18.10 mobile internet - SIM card not recognized

Tags: mobile-broadband

What could be a reason, why my mobile internet UMTS card is not recognized by modem-manager-gui or by the NetworkManager? My laptop is a Lenovo X1. I once saw it recognized, but after a reboot it disappeared.